# How many functions can I put in the main functiion?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing an automation tool to add and remove directories, and to check the size of a file in bytes. After, I have written all the functions, when I call them in the main function, I'll either get an error or no prompt at all. My aim is to be able to select a number that correlates with a tool you want to use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil

print ("Welcome to my automation tool.")

user_response = input("""Choose a number that correlates with the tool you wish to use
            1. Remove a directory
            2. Add a directory
            3. Find a file size in bytes

Option: """)

if user_response == "1":
    def rmDir(delDir):
        if os.path.isdir(delDir) == True:#Check whether or not the directory path exists, using the stored variable 'delDir'
        delDir = input("Enter the directory to be removed: ")
        print ("Directory Exists. Deleting now...")
        shutil.rmtree(delDir) #Removes an entire directory
    else:
        print (delDir, "Doesn't exist. Please try again.")

if user_response == "2":
    def newDir(addDir):
        if os.path.isdir(addDir) == True:
            addDir = input("Enter the directory to be created: ")
            print ("Directory already exists.")
        else:
            print ("Creating new directory ",addDir)
            os.makedirs(addDir)

def main():
    delDir = input("Enter the directory to be removed: ")
    rmDir(delDir)
    newDir(addDir)
    addDir = input("Enter the directory to be created: ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What does the question title have to do with the question?

Comment: @kaya3 I was thinking that too, I think that he thinks the problem is that there are too many functions in main which isn’t possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the defining outside the if condition and put in the if condition the calling ,

In main you should put the if condition and the input().

If you want to repeate more times the execution of the program you can use a while cycle

Comment: I did call it in the main function. I called them both.

Comment: The code in the main() is not clear, yoau should put in if condition The function calling and externally the defining

Comment: In your code if you enter 1 the function new dir is not defined, if you enter 2 the function rmDir is not defined so compiler put error in both cases

Comment: In the rmDir you got an indentation error for the else

Answer (score 1):

You are using addDir before you are defining it in the main() function, addDir is a local variable not global. Also, make sure that you are running the program directly and not from another file (that is obviously what `if “__name__” == __main__` is.